# How do I silence vlc output from bash script completely?

Tags: linux, bash, vlc

I have a script I wrote for myself and it uses vlc somewhere towards to end and I need it to stop outputting anything it wants but keep my own outputs (so no "clear").

i have used the parameters: "-q" and "--no-sout-x264-quiet" but to no avail, it still outputs ugly msgs, ie: "Warning: call to rand()" and "Blocked: ..." and "Gtk-WARNING ** ..."

i tried redirecting 'vlc ... > err.log',  it dont help...

(edit[forgot to add]: the redirect '>' doesnt work, file is empty)

i searched in vlc -H but its massive and there are >20 "quiet" keyword, non of which seem like they would help

Please help me :'(

Comment: It looks like it's outputting to STDERR. You need to redirect STDERR to /dev/null to make it really quiet. But how will you know if something's wrong?

Comment: its a personal script, and if it dont work i'll know, because the scripts purpose is to play a file with vlc, and besides I cant make use of the errors...

Comment: Exactly, so redirect the **errors** to /dev/null if you're not going to use them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Normal redirection via ">" will just redirect "standard output". You must use "2>" to redirect the "standard error" stream.

```
vlc .. > out.log 2> err.log
```

Answer (score 2):

A "great" guide to redirection in `bash` (both STDOUT and STDERR) can be found [here](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-3.html)

Comment: so, don't you think I deserve a little upvote? I can edit my answer to say "A great guide to redirection..."

Comment: i'm new, by upvote do u mean you answer, the ^ arrow? if yes, i cant, i have less than 15 points :(

Comment: you have my upvote :) and I upvoted the question so krack has 15 points now.