# How to silence console output from vlc module in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, vlc, libvlc

(Xubuntu 18.04, Python 3.6.9)

I am working on a little application for myself with very simple usage of the vlc module. It's a console-based application using curses, and vlc is interjecting its output in the middle of my terminal interface. I can't figure out how to silence it. Have read libvlc docs, nothing about it that I can find. Have tried the advice from [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6339981/how-do-i-silence-vlc-output-from-bash-script-completely), no success after setting `sys.stderr = open('stderr.txt', 'w+')`. Have not been able to locate anything in the libvlc docs or running `vlc -H`. I don't really care if I'm able to access the output; I just need it to not print in the console.

Here is all my VLC-related code, probably unnecessary in this case:

```
def vlc_init():
    global vlc_instance, media_player
    vlc_instance = vlc.Instance('--no-xlib') # VLC asked me to pass '--no-xlib' *shrug*
    media_player = vlc_instance.media_player_new()

def set_new_media(media_path):
    media = vlc_instance.media_new(media_path)
    media_player.set_media(media)
```

Does anyone know what I can do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `vlc -H`:

```sh
Console logger (console)
 -q, --quiet, --no-quiet        Be quiet
                      (default disabled)
   Turn off all messages on the console.
```

So yea, just call your vlc instance with one of those flags enabled, and redirect stderr to */dev/null* for good measure.
`vlc_instance = vlc.Instance('--no-xlib -q > /dev/null 2>&1')`

Comment: Perfect solution, thanks so much! Am I correct in thinking that this is a Linux-specific solution, at least the `> /dev/null 2>&1` part? Like these are bash commands that are getting run?

Comment: oh yea yea, it is.  Didn't even think about it 'cuz VLC's been just about standard-issue in Linux distros for years.  believe it would be fine on Mac's, 'cuz they have a similar OS.  Win's the odd one out  --  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4507312/how-to-redirect-stderr-to-null-in-cmd-exe